# Изменение представления числа

Tags: c++

Как в программе перевести число из двоичной системы в десятичную и наоборот?

Comment: Вопрос непонятен. Укажите представление исходного числа и результата.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Операции с двоичными числами в с++](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/521749/%d0%9e%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d1%81-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d1%81)

Answer (score 2):

Для преобразования строк десятичного представления и двоичное и обратно, можно использовать пару функций: itoa (не входит в стандарт) и strtol.

Число - строка:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main ()
{
      int num = 7;
      char out[33] = { 0 };

      itoa(num, out, 10);
      printf ("Dec: %s.", out);
      itoa(num, out, 2);
      printf ("Bin: %s.\n", out);
}
```

Строка - число:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main ()
{
    char nums[] = "1001 1001";
    char *end;

    printf ("Dec: %ld. Bin: %ld.\n", strtol(nums, &end, 10), strtol(nums, NULL, 2));
}
```

Comment: Это все понятно, а если у пользователя запросить ввести число для перевода из bin в dec и наоборот?

Comment: Если у попросить пользователя ввести число, то будет то же самое. Вводить строку можно функцией scanf (или другими средствами C++), а потом эту строку пропускать через пару strtol/itoa.

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться 2-мя методами:

1. Это объединения (union'ы) с битовыми полями.
2. Воспользоваться логическими операциями

Во втором случае код будет выглядить так (проверил, работает):

```
int num;
scanf("%i",&num);
unsigned char i;
for(i=0;i<sizeof(num)*8;i++)
    printf("%i",(num & (1<<(sizeof(num)*8-i-1)) ) >> (sizeof(num)*8-i-1));
```

Идея в том, чтобы взять исходное число, перемножить его с единицей с помощью операции И. Мы получим низжий разряд. Затем единицу сдвинуть влево и перемножить с ней опять же исходное число операцией И. Мы получим разряд выше. Сдвинем получившееся число назад, к низжему разряду. И так далее. Но в данном коде вычисление идёт от верхнего разряда к нижнему, чтобы вывести на экран число не задом наперёд.

Comment: На самом деле его можно ещё лучше оптимизировать.

Answer (score 0):

Проверить какие биты установлены в единицу.
 
14 -> 1110

```
char bin[4];
int v = 14;
for(int i=1,j=0;i<16;i*=2,j++){
   bin[j] = (char)48 + v&i;
}
```

Не уверен что правильно понял вопрос, но надеюсь что чем-то поможет...